# Is there a way to charge as a move action (or lower)?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, charge, move-action

I'm very fond of quirky builds, even if the optimization is horrible. I'm working around a polearm charger right now (no mounts - mounts are lame). [My other question asks about ways to turn during a charge.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/169261/what-way-are-there-ways-to-turn-during-a-charge) In this question, though, I'm trying to reduce the action it takes to charge or at least make it possible to use a standard action afterwards. There is a class I want to use (DM approved) that has many special attacks that require standard actions my goal is to use a charge to get into melee distance then follow up with one such attack. Since stuff you know moves I want to be able to use the attack on the same turn. In our game the action rules are changed in two ways you have two standard actions and can run (or charge) 4x your movement speed in a straight line assuming you don’t have anything that allows you to turn such as veer but lose your next turn if you use the extra movement repeatedly. Ie out of breath.

Is there a way to charge and have a standard action (when you get 2 per turn as a house rule) left over afterwards (including ways that lower the actual distance)?

All rulebooks are allowed; 3PP content and 3.5e  are allowed on a case-by-case basis, though the answer is usually yes.

Comment: Hopefully, my question is more clear and focused now feel free to ask if you need more clarity.

Comment: The answer is almost-certainly “No,” though I’m not terribly inclined myself to do the leg-work to determine that. It may well be that no one else is, either, in which case the question goes unanswered. But questions are allowed to go unanswered—nothing here is going to cause problems with our rules or with our voting schemes. It *certainly* isn’t too broad—like I said, I doubt there are *any* answers, much less too many. It’s a valid question, it just isn’t likely to see a lot of success in the answering department. That’s OK.

Comment: Can you clarify what specifically you're trying to accomplish here? I would be very surprised if there's a way to do this, since a charge includes an attack and anything that allows you to attack as a move action would likely be ridiculously overpowered. Do you actually need to *charge* specifically?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery I'm almost certain the goal *is* to be ridiculously overpowered since by level 6 a dedicated *3.5* charger punches 3–4 CRs above his weight anyway. `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

Since you say in your other post that 3.5e is allowed, I'm going to make a suggestion from there.

Spiritual Totem barbarian ACF (*Complete Champion* p.46), with the Lion totem, gains the [Pounce](http://dndsrd.net/monsterTypes.html#pounce) ability at level 1, in place of Fast Movement.

> **Pounce (Ex):** When a creature with this special attack makes a charge, it can follow with a full attack - including rake attacks if the creature also has the rake ability.

This isn't *exactly* "charging as a move action", but does allow a Full Attack after a charge.

Comment: That won't work for reasons I stated in my update.

Comment: Depends how you interpret it. By RAW, it says nothing about you needing to jump, just that you can full-attack when you charge. Yes, it's *called* Pounce, which has certain connotations, but that's much like 5e's Sneak Attack not actually requiring sneaking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on what your end goal is and it's difficult to prove a negative, but **as far as I know this does not exist**. There are options to charge as a readied action ([Rhino Charge](http://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Rhino%20Charge), [Vigilant Charger](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Vigilant%20Charger)) or even to make two charges in one turn ([Barracuda Dash](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Barracuda%20Dash)), but nothing I've seen to charge with a move action.

Actions have a hierarchy: you can turn a standard action into a move action, but you can't turn a move action into a standard action. You're looking to both convert a move to a standard alongside a method to turn a standard into a charge (which Rhino Charge and Vigilant Charger can both do, to varying degrees). I can't say with 100% certainty that this doesn't exist, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't.

Perhaps if you can clarify your end goal, something else can get you there?

Comment: I updated the op hopefully that helps