# How does alcohol affect a character?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

How do I calculate the affects of alcohol on someone that's been drinking as far as combat, using skills, and just the aftermath of a hangover?

Comment: There is already a [similar question here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1449/penalties-for-being-drunk).

Comment: @Octopus I think you're right, so I'm flagging it as a possible dup.