# Are there any spells or other effects that remove intoxication?

Tags: dnd-5e

In DnD 5e, there's no official rule for what happens when you are severely intoxicated. However, many DMs will houserule something along the lines of progressive levels of exhaustion, disadvantage on attacks, penalties to CHA checks, or the like.

Whether or not alcohol intoxication has a gameplay/mechanical effect or merely an RP-driving effect, are there any effects in the game that remove it?

Specifically:

- Are there any officially published (anything on WoTC website, including UA) rules, spells, or effects that directly and explicitly deal with removing intoxication in 5e?
- If not, are there any rules, spells, or affects that could be reasonably construed to affect intoxication?

Other helpful information: if there is an effect that explicitly mentions intoxication in a previous edition, that would be useful enough to post as an answer. For example, if there was a way to use the Medicine skill specifically to remove drunkenness in 3.5, that could be extended to 5e or adapted as a reasonable homebrew.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Since alcohol in large amounts acts like a poison - D&D 5e doesn't differentiate between poison and toxin, to my knowledge - you can use spells such as "Lesser Restoration" to get rid of its effects.

> **Lesser Restoration:** You touch a creature and can end either one disease or one condition afflicting it. The condition can be blinded, deafened, paralyzed, or **poisoned**.

Also the following spell:

> **Protection from Poison:** You touch a creature. **If it is poisoned, you neutralize the poison**. If more than one poison afflicts the target, you neutralize one poison that you know is present, or you neutralize one at random.   For the duration, the target has advantage on saving throws against being poisoned, and it has resistance to poison damage.

Both spells are level 2.

If your DM also gives you levels of exhaustion for drinking (which is a bit over the top, in my opinion) you can either sleep it off or use the "Greater Restoration" spell to remove one level of exhaustion.

#### Addition:

As @Icyfire mentioned, there are other ways of getting rid of poisoning, which includes alcohol poisoning.

Those are (no guarantee for completeness):

- spell *Heroes' Feast* (credit goes to @Icyfire):

  > [...] The creature is cured of all diseases and poison, [...]
- A paladin's class feature "Lay on hands" (credit goes to @Icyfire):

  > [...] Alternatively, you can expend 5 hit points from your pool of healing to cure the target of one disease or neutralize one poison affecting it. [...]
- A wild magic surge (credit goes to @KumosAgosta):

  > 53-54: You are immune to being intoxicated by alcohol for the next 5d6 days.
- Transmuter's stone (School of Transmutation wizard, level 14):

  > You remove all curses, diseases, and poisons affecting a creature that you touch with the transmuter’s stone.
- *Raise Dead*: You could technically kill yourself and get revived, due to the following passage in the description of *Raise Dead*. I personally wouldn't recommend this method, but that might just be me. (Note that this also goes for other resurrection spells like *Resurrection* or *True Resurrection*)

  > This spell also neutralizes any poisons and cures nonmagical diseases that affected the creature at the time it died.

A quick search for "poison" in the Player's Handbook yielded the following additional results, which only provide benefits (unless you want to get drunk) to yourself, not to others:

- Druid/Circle of the Land, level 10 feature *Nature's Ward*: Immunity to poison
- Monk level 10 feature *Purity of Body*: Immunity to poison

#### Non-PHB features etc.

- XGtE: Description of *Brewer's Supplies*:

  > Medicine. This tool proficiency grants additional insight when you treat anyone suffering from alcohol poisoning or when you can use alcohol to dull pain.
- VGtM: Yuan-Ti Pureblood player race: Poison immunity
- VGtM: *Ki-Rin* lair effect:

  > Curses, diseases, and poisons affecting good-aligned
  >   creatures are suppressed when those creatures are
  >   within 3 miles of the lair.

There might be other creatures in the MM that have similar effects to the *Ki-Rin's* lair effect, but I don't feel like skipping through any more poison damage attacks and monsters' poison resistances, Volo's Guide had enough of those.

Comment: as mentioned by Icyfire, you don't cure the hangover (although you could probably prevent it largely if you remove the poison before you sleep).

Comment: Venom, toxin and poison aren't all interchangeable, but everything is poison once it's in your body doing its thing, so there shouldn't be any need to distinguish for the purposes of lesser restoration anyway.

Answer (score 10):

### Alcohol is a poison

After some [quick searching](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/1695/32262), I found that the 3.0 Arms and Equipment Guide contains rules for drunkeness. In that section, it refers to a *Neutralize Poison* spell (pg. 32):

> The character regains 1 point of Dexterity and Wisdom for each full hour after consuming the last alcoholic beverage, usually feeling terrible in the process. *Neutralize poison* negates the damaging effects of alcohol (but not the hangover).

Many spells and abilities in 5e can remove poisoning. An incomplete list includes the Paladin's Lay on Hands, Heroes' Feast, Lesser Restoration, and Protection from Poison. Since you allow extrapolation from previous editions, any of these spells and abilities should reasonably be able to cure drunkness (but apparently not hangeovers!)

Comment: Well, that's great for 3.x. Unfortunately, while 3.x is a similar system to 5e, it's different enough to not be easily comparable. When did you last see a 5e Wizard with 50+ Int?

Comment: @VHS, from the question: "Other helpful information: if there is an effect that explicitly mentions intoxication in a previous edition, that would be useful enough to post as an answer. "

Answer (score 0):

I believe alcohol is implicitly under the "Poisoned" rule because alcohol *is* technically a poison. As for "severe intoxication", I think it's a matter of DM-interpretation. **As for the actual answer to your question:**

The spell *Neutralize Poison* from 3.5e could be easily adapted into 5e.

*Protection from Poison* and *Lesser Restoration* are both in 5e and would equally be valid.

I am not familiar with anything explicitly stated by WotC about Intoxication, but I normally just say "Poisoned" for it myself unless the characters get *really* drunk.... but I have my own system for that.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast, functionally, yes, it does replace Neutralize Poison. So does Protection from Poison. I just thought it worthwhile to mention a past example as well as in-edition examples since OP asked about it.